# MissingSchema exception when using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a person class which gives me the details of the person as shown below:

**Datatracker.py class**

```
@dataclass
class Person:
    resource_uri: str
    id: int
    name: str
    name_from_draft: str
    ascii: str
    ascii_short: Optional[str]
    user: str
    time: str
    photo: str
    photo_thumb: str
    biography: str
    consent: bool
```

Now I defined a function which would act as a generator and prints people details in the datatracker based on timestamps:

```
def people(self, since="1970-01-01T00:00:00", until="2038-01-19T03:14:07", name_contains=None):
       """
       A generator that returns people recorded in the datatracker. As of April
       2018, there are approximately 21500 people recorded.
       Parameters:
           since         -- Only return people with timestamp after this
           until         -- Only return people with timestamp before this
           name_contains -- Only return peopls whose name containing this string
       Returns:
           An iterator, where each element is as returned by the person() method
       """
       url = self.base_url + "/api/v1/person/person/?time__gt=" + since + "&time__lt=" + until
       if name_contains is not None:
           url = url + "&name__contains=" + name_contains
       while url is not None:
           r = self.session.get(url, verify=True)
           meta = r.json()['meta']
           objs = r.json()['objects']
           url = meta['next']
           for obj in objs:
               yield obj
```

when I try printing only the names of the person from another file, although it prints all the names, it brings upon an unusual error as shown below.
**app.py **

```
import requests
import datatracker
import rfcindex

user=datatracker.DataTracker()
user_people = user.people("1970-01-01T00:00:00", "2038-01-19T03:14:07", "")
 for u in user_people:
    print(u['name'])
```

```
Error: raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/api/v1/person/person/?limit=20&name__contains=&time__gt=2010-01-01&time__lt=2020-01-01&offset=20': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///api/v1/person/person/?limit=20&name__contains=&time__gt=2010-01-01&time__lt=2020-01-01&offset=20?
```

Kindly help

Comment: I think that error message just means that you need to prefix your URL with something like "http://".

Comment: I am getting the names, however this error also pops up along with it, I am not supposed to change the class and def function but I can do something in the last file where I have imported the other python files..kindly help on how I could modify that

Comment: You just need to set `self.base_url` correctly.

Comment: error shows you that you have wrong URL - you have only `/api/...` but you need full url `http://some_domain.com/api/...`

Comment: The self base url is been pointed correctly as to https://datatracker.ietf.org and ideally when I try running in browser, like https://datatracker.ietf.org/api/person/person/, I am getting the xml file, from which all I have to take is only the name..which I am unable to do

Comment: `self.base_url` must start with something like "http://"

Comment: the self.base_url is https type.This is there in the base file which should not be modified.Could I make any changes in the last file displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following trivial script duplicates your problem:

```
import requests
result = requests.get('/api/v1')
```

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 3, in <module>
    result = requests.get('/api/v1')
...
Several lines removed for brevity
...
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/api/v1': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///api/v1?
```

The `requests` library is trying to tell you to prefix your `self.base_url` with "http://", as in

```
self.base_url = 'http://' + hostname
```

For your specific case, you just need add one line to your code:

```
import requests
import datatracker
import rfcindex

user = datatracker.DataTracker()
user.base_url = 'https://' + user.base_url
user_people = user.people("1970-01-01T00:00:00", "2038-01-19T03:14:07", "")
    for u in user_people:
        print(u['name'])
```

This complete example shows how to get the first 20 names from the site using a class with the same problem as the one you are using:

```
import requests

class DataTracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_url = 'datatracker.ietf.org'

    def people(self):
        url = self.base_url + '/api/v1/person/person'
        result = requests.get(url)
        data = result.json()
        for value in data['objects']:
            yield value['name']

data_tracker = DataTracker()
data_tracker.base_url = 'https://' + data_tracker.base_url
for person in data_tracker.people():
    print(person)
```

If you can't get this example program to work, then you have some other problem.

Comment: where do I add this script in?

Comment: Where is `self.base_url` initialized?

Comment: It is done in the base file which is not to be modified.All I can modify is the last file where I import this python file

Comment: Is there a constructor for the class that accepts a `base_url` parameter?

Comment: Yes, there is one in the base class which is defined like this:  def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.base_url = https://datatracker.ietf.org, but I am not supposed to make any changes onto this

Comment: I modified my answer to show you how to modify `self.base_url` after calling the constructor, so you don't have to modify the class.

Comment: Yes, see the latest change to the answer.

Comment: I tried doing that, but then this error came in : urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //datatracker.ietf.org/api/v1/person/person/?time__gt=1970-01-01T00:00:00&time__lt=2038-01-19T03:14:07&name__contains= (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001999D07AC18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

Comment: That is a completely different problem. If you run the example I added to the end of my answer, do you still get that error message?

Comment: The code runs seperately but the same code is there in datatracker.py and all I have to do is import and call that function..which i am unable to do from app.py

Comment: I wrote a stand-alone script and added it to the end of the answer. If you run that script, do you still get the MaxRetryError exception? If so, you have some kind of networking problem I can't help you with.

Comment: I do not get the error when i write the standalone script provided, but this is the same script which is there in the datatracker.py file I have attached.The requirement is to call that and print the names

Comment: If you made the one line change I suggested, and you get the MaxRetryError, then I do not have enough information to help you.